# Setting ViewModel data value in afterRender callback function breaks Knockout.js bindings

Tags: knockout.js

I have a very complex jquery template that I bind with javascript-based `ViewModel` data via the knockout.js framework. Actually, I have an `observableArray` of `ViewModel` objects within another `ViewModel` that gets bound to my template.

Within my template, I have several DOM elements that trigger certain events as their values change. For instance, I have a radio button set that changes the binding of a select list (as well as enablement) when a value is selected, which in turn clears the value of a textbox (as well as enablement), by altering various observable properties within my bound `ViewModel`. These triggers help guide the UX flow for the end-user, as well as ensuring certain values are saved or cleared as needed. All this works fine.

However...

When I retrieve initial data from my database and populate my `ViewModels`, then bind the `ViewModels` to the template, the triggers fire, as they should. However, I **do not** want the underlying observable values cleared due to the triggers firing. So, what I devised is a way to initially set my `ViewModel`'s `IsInitialData` observable value to `true`, which my triggers use to determine whether to clear certain values. However, I want to set these properties to `false` after my template binding is completed, and before any user interaction is performed.

What made most sense to me was to use the `afterRender` callback to set the `IsInitialData` property to `false`. This way, my triggers would fire normally after the initial data has been bound. My `afterRender` callback function looks like this:

```
function resetIsInitialDataAttribute(nodesArray, dataValue) {
    alert(dataValue.IsInitialData()); // Displays 'true'
    dataValue.IsInitialData(false);
    alert(dataValue.IsInitialData()); // Displays 'false'
}
```

Interesting, I can read the value fine within the above function, even after setting the value.

However...

Once I set the value in the `afterRender` callback function above, my observable binding seems to break. To test, I have placed a div within my template to serialize my `observableArray` so I can display all of my `ViewModel`'s values:

```
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(locationsViewModel.locations)"></div>
```

If I don't set the `IsInitialData` property within my `afterRender` callback, then as I modify my DOM elements that have been bound to my `ViewModel`'s observable properties, the above div instantly displays the modified values. But, if I do set my `IsInitialData` property in the callback function, the above div no longer displays any changed values in my `ViewModel`.

Does anyone know why setting my `ViewModel`'s property within the `afterRender` callback function causes problems? Is there an alternative means for me to set the `IsInitialData` `ViewModel` property after my initial database binding is completed? I looked through the jQuery.tmpl documentation for any sort of callback that I can use that takes place after binding my data, but found nothing usable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is essentially a version of this issue: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/133.  Also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070716/knockout-js-template-not-updating-ui-binding-on-a-dependantobservable).

During `afterRender` the elements are not actually in the DOM yet.  Setting the value of an observable in this code (or in a binding) that was just bound to an element will cause the dependentObservable used in that element's binding to be re-evaluated.  It will see that the element is not in the DOM and think that it should dispose of itself.

An easy workaround is to set your value in your `afterRender` like:

```
setTimeout(function() { dataValue.IsInitialData(false); }, 0);
```

This will let the current execution finish at which time your elements will be in the DOM.

Comment: I did have to modify the code to:

    setTimeout(function() { dataValue.IsInitialData(false); }, 100);

This was due to the current execution taking longer with multiple collections of DOM elements being bound, depending on how many items are being pulled from the database.

Comment: That is kind of odd.  setTimeout(..., 0) still can't run until the current execution finishes.  Not sure if there are any other factors at play.

Comment: It turns out that even with the extended length of time for the timeout, periodically (and quite sporadically), my DOM elements execute their change (select list) triggers, and my ViewModel's explicit property subscription fires, AFTER the dataValue.IsInitialData() property change is set within my afterRender callback. This causes some headaches for me, because certain property values are cleared that shouldn't be cleared unless an actual user performs the DOM manipulations.

Comment: Not quite sure without some more details.  Doesn't sound normal.  One thing that you could try quick is how it works with Knockout 1.3 beta.  The original issue is resolved in 1.3 (http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/), so you could try it without the setTimeout to simplify your case.

Comment: The 1.3 beta version resolved my issue! Now, what I had to do was still use the setTimeout, otherwise it would still try to set the value too early, but I set the throttle on my IsInitialData observable to 2 seconds (to provide ample time), with setting its default value to true (even for non-initial data). If I didn't set a default value, then the object would be seen as undefined initially. My IsInitialData property now looks like this: this.IsInitialData = ko.observable(true).extend({ throttle: 2000 });